# T-SQL : how to use exec to insert into table not previously created?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
Declare @strSQL varchar(max);
set @strSQL = N'REALLY LONG QUERY';
exec (@strSQL) at <LinkedServerName>;
```

I did this because the query is longer than 8000 characters (it cannot be changed, it just has too many columns). It works, but I need to insert it into a temporal table that does not yet exist. So, I do not want to run the create table before hand. So, where should I write INTO tmp_table for correct syntax?

For example, this does not work:

```
exec (@strSQL) INTO tmp_table at <LinkedServerName>;
```

Comment: you either add that `INTO tmp_table` in the dynamic SQL or create the table first and then use `INSERT INTO tmp_table EXEC(....`

Comment: And why do you need dynamic sql for this?

Comment: Put that all in @strSQL

Comment: Are you using aliases on your table names? For example, if you have the tables "Customers", "CustomerOrders", and "Orders", using the name aliases "c", "co", and "o" can shrink the size of your query significantly.

Comment: The linked server is an Oracle DB, and I want to bring data into an SQL Server table. The query is long because it has 137 columns, not because of bad design or union alls. Yes, I am using aliases for the tables, a and b respectvely. Thanks for all your help, but none seem to work.

Comment: Do you need for the temporary table to be on the local server or on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @strSQL varchar(max);
if object_id('tempdb..MyTempTable') is not null drop table tempdb.dbo.MyTempTable
set @strSQL = N'select * into tempdb.dbo.MyTempTable from (REALLY LONG QUERY) k';
exec (@strSQL) at <LinkedServerName>;
-- for check of existence of table for linkedserver add it into @strSQL
```

or

replace *tempdb.dbo.MyTempTable* with temp table `##Table` (for local server)

or

decompose and normalize your model, if you have qry with thousands chars you don't need dynamical qry but rethink your solution - for example use views or pivot your output